# Jquery button arrow function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

```js
 $("#btn").on("click",()=>{
  var el = $(this);
 el.parent().find("#lbl").html("a");
 });
 
  $("#btn1").on("click",function(){
  var el = $(this);
 el.parent().find("#lbl").html("a"); 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dvHeader">
<label id="lbl">Hello WOrld</label>
<button id="btn">
Button 1!
</button>
<button id="btn1">
Button 2!
</button>
</div>
```

I'm starting to learn an arrow function. I am wondering the two code above for button function don't work properly in an arrow function. But the other one is working properly. Did I do wrong?.

Comment: @user4642212 no sorry.

Comment: with arrow function you cant use `$(this)`

Comment: @jack why?. can you give a documentation URL so I can read?.

Comment: on [w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_arrow_function.asp)

Comment: Because `this` inside your arrow function refers to window object and not to the button, take a look on [**this**](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26/) to learn more

Comment: @SaymoinSam Thank you. `No self-referencing`. I get it now.

Comment: @KiRa maybe you want to use the event object, take a look on my answer

Comment: @SaymoinSam It solve my problem. I thought that `$(this)` can be use. Sample above is just my example using `$(this)`, but thank you for effort

Comment: @jack That’s not W3C. That’s W3Schools. There’s better documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 1):

But if you want to use arrow functions in your jQuery event handlers you can use the `event` object inside your listener like this

```js
$("#btn").on("click", e => $(e.target).parent().find("#lbl").html("a"));

$("#btn1").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parent().find("#lbl").html("a");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dvHeader">
  <label id="lbl">Hello WOrld</label>
  <button id="btn">Button 1!</button>
  <button id="btn1">Button 2!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed you code to achieve what you are trying to do:
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mnukqpzg/)

Also change your function to as below:

```
$("#btn").on("click",()=>{
  var el = document.getElementById("lbl");
  el.textContent = 'a';
 });
```

Comment: if that was the case then it could be just `$("#btn").on("click", _=> $("#lbl").html("a"));` as he's using jQuery

Comment: I just added to not change HTML rather only update text-content but you are also correct :)

Comment: If it was only for text content then `.html("a")` would be `.text("a")` but I saw the OP using `.html()` that's all

Comment: Yep, still it is assumption of purpose from my end so no point discussing lot on it but still you are right that can also be option.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use 「event.currentTarget」.
For example, below code works.

```
$("#btn").on("click", (event) => {
    var el = $(event.currentTarget);
    el.parent().find("#lbl").html("a");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test page</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dvHeader">
        <label id="lbl">Hello World</label>
        <button id="btn">
            Button 1!
        </button>
        <button id="btn1">
            Button 2!
        </button>
    </div>
    <script>
        $("#btn").on("click", (event) => {
            var el = $(event.currentTarget);
            el.parent().find("#lbl").html("a");
        });

        $("#btn1").on("click", function(){
            var el = $(this);
            el.parent().find("#lbl").html("a"); 
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```